# Redirect problem with ngnix

Tags: 301-redirect

I have a web site and i want ot redirect my clients from example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in https. I fould a question similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www) but it did not solve my problem. When trying to access https://example.com it loads forever. the redirect from a mttp page works perfectly.
here is the example of my ngnix config and the things that i have tried.

```
server {
    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    # redirect all non-www traffic to the www version
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # location of the signed SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}



server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # location of the signed SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...

    

    location / {
        # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea of why the server is not redirecting to www ?